# C++ reference bug

Tags: c++, function, reference

I tried to understand how c++ references work and I tried to write the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
int& func();
int main()
{
    std::cout <<func()<< std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

 int& func()
{
    int x = 23;
    return x;
}
```

for my understanding, the int x which was initialized in the function will be erased after the func ends and then the value that the function is returning will point to something that doesn`t exist.
But when I print it I get 23 in the console.
How does it possible?

Comment: [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is undefined.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: I expected it to fail compiling because the value that the func returns is reference to something that dosen`t exists. can you explain where I am wrong?

Comment: If you crank up your compiler warning level (which you should do), and treat all warnings as errors (which is highly recommended), [you will get a warning/error in many such cases](https://godbolt.org/z/fh-0ok). But not in all cases. It is ultimately your responsibility to make sure you are not returning a dangling reference. The compiler cannot always ensure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is written in the memory inside `func()`, but you are wrong in "doesn't exist" after return.
Why would it not exist, did anything else overwrite that memory? You can't be sure. It's undefined behavior.

You are just returning a memory adress from `func()` which after return is made available for other variables. But if that (now available) memory adress is not overwriten, it will hold the value 23.. Until the end of days ;)

Here's @George 's reference to undefined behavior :
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Furthermore your code might have some errors... Anyway, look at this and it shall solve your worries
[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/2923755)

Comment: @Liroshka how is it failing?

Comment: same applies to this?:https://pastebin.com/7AJcteYn

Comment: @Liroshka No, it's different, but pone for leaking memory.

Comment: how is it different?

Comment: @Liroshka You allocate the necessary memory dynamically? That quite makes a difference.

Comment: What is different? that even after the function will end this value won`t be overriden?

Comment: @Liroshka Have you read the links?

Comment: Why did I even attempt to answer this.. Sure didn't need the downvote given my modest rep

Comment: @Liroshka If you aren't satisfied with the answers from the duplicate, clarify and improve your question please, instead of wasting everyone's time in endless comment discussions.